# data from a jsonobject in android

Tags: android, json

The below is called from a string url and returns a json object which has an json array inside, but something else is not working, can anyone show me how to access the data inside?

```
      {"data":[{"8196":{"booking_id":"8150","client_id":"107","venue_id":null}}]
```

Comment: Show us you current code, and explain what do you mean by: "something else is not working".

Comment: your json output is itself wrong can you plz put your above json output here (http://json.parser.online.fr/) you will get error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input... since have a look at your json output at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String jsonStr = "{\"data\":[{\"8196\":{\"booking_id\": \"8150\",\"client_id\": \"107\",\"venue_id\": null}}]}";

try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator it = o.keys();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String name = (String) it.next();
            o = o.getJSONObject(name);
            int bookingId = o.getInt("booking_id");
            int clientId = o.getInt("client_id");
            int venueId = o.optInt("venue_id");

            Log.v("TEST", String.format("Booking ID: %s -- Client ID: %s -- Venue ID: %s", bookingId, clientId, venueId));
        }

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I guess this is what you'll want. By the way, the JSON you posted is malformed. It's missing a } in the end.

Comment: Thanks guys Martins code is roughly what I have been trying already, but were the object is("8196") will always change with out me know what it is??

Comment: I'm trying to call the object ("8196") without actually naming it??

Comment: Added an iterator over the keys to the code. Should solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you martin much appreciated, also works with strings:) works a treat.

Comment: Still having problems with this json, it will work with one object, when I have two or more bookings it will not iterate through it:( tried all sorts.{"data":[{"8272":{"booking_id":"8221","client_id":"108","venue_id":null},"8281":{"booking_id":"8229","client_id":"71","venue_id":null}}]} returns no value for 8281

Answer (score 0):

You first need to decode the JSON string. The JSON sting you got in return is actually a serialized version of a JSON object.

You need to decode that string into a native Java Object.

There are a number of methods to this in Java.  You can start by checking out the Java section at json.org.

Comment: Sorry forgot the ending }, that wasn't the problem just forgot to copy it on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the value of key venue_id is null. You can replace null value with empty string(""), try it.